# Why is Debug Mode slower than Release in VS?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've Googled this already and usually the responses are fairly complex and I don't really understand all the jargon. Is there a simple explanation for why Debug mode is so slow? Why not just always run in Release?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Debug mode has all optimizations turned off, to make sure the connected debugger works as expected. A Release will have a lot of optimizations switched on.

Simpler than that I cannot state it.

Comment: Can the optimizations interfere with the code's execution in some instances?

Comment: Yes. Dead code will be removed, loops can be optimized, etcetera. But this doesn't fall in the "simple explanation" category ;-).

Comment: There are *many* things that can be subtly different between a debug and release build. In addition to those Bart mentions there's the debug heap, zero initialisation of variables, possible race conditions due to the difference in speed, use of diagnostic debug-only code, etc.  One of the main reasons that the debug version is significantly slower is because of these extra diagnostics.

Comment: as to _why_ you want to run in Debug, it's because those extra diagnostics are doing lots of useful stuff that help you catch bugs in your program so that you have more chance of the release build working.  Don't be tempted to skip the debug build just because it's too slow or puts up errors you don't understand.

Comment: Bart, can you please talk about debugging symbols and pdbs, and whether that has anything to do with release builds running faster than debug builds